# Whats the most Pythonic way to pass a large number of arguments to multiprocessing map?

Tags: python, list, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm trying to run a stochastic simulation in parallel using Python's multiprocessing library 50 times, and compare the parallel execution time to the sequential execution time.

I've written a function that calls my stochastic simulation function, `parallelfunc` this is passed as the first argument to the multiprocessing map command.

```
def parallelfunc(v):
    gillespie_tau_leaping(start_state, LHS, stoch_rate, state_change_array)
```

At the moment the second argument to map is as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #para_proc = list(range(50))
    start = datetime.utcnow()
    with Pool() as p:
        pool_results = p.map(parallelfunc, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]) 
    end = datetime.utcnow()
    sim_time = end - start
    print(f"Simualtion utc time:\n{sim_time}")
```

I've tried a few methods to pass an iterable of length 50 as the second argument to map, including a list in the form of `para_proc` this didn't work.

I then tried a list comprehension `[x for x in range(50)]` only I think the for loop really slowed down the execution time and it wasn't much faster than running the simulation 50 times sequentially which isn't what I want.

Is there a more Pythonic way that won't heavily impact the speed to do this?

Cheers

Comment: Just pass `range(1, 51)` directly? It doesn't slow anything, and it avoids typing out 50 numbers. I think you're suffering from thinking `range` must be converted to a `list` to be useful; it doesn't, it's a sequence on it's own, so `[x for x in range(50)]` is ridiculous (if you needed a `list`, you'd just do `list(range(50))`, but you rarely do). Also, `range(50)` is not the same as the `list` literal you passed, it includes `0`, but excludes `50`. `range(1, 51)` is equivalent.

Comment: Passing `range(1, 51)` only seems to run 1 process?

Comment: If it only runs one process, so would passing `[1, 2, 3, >..., 48, 49, 50]` as the second argument; in terms of how Python would behave, they're identical. But that seems unlikely; simply creating the `Pool` should launch all the processes, whether or not you use them.